# Scan and identify bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, reverse-engineering, mac-address

I've tried to post this question on [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/15991/scan-and-identify-bluetooth-device), but it was closed as off topic. I'm not sure this is the right place to post it as it's not purely software, but still.

---

Being a quasi-newbie in this game, I'm trying to identify a device which communicates on 2.4Ghz, a Bluetooth mouse talking to his dongle.

My goal is to identify the MAC address of the device and then reverse the protocol.

Knowing that my only documentation about it is his chipset and the associated datasheet :

Which are the basics step to follow to achieve this ?

What hardware and software tool should I use ?

Would dumping the dongle's firmware be a possible approach ? If yes why ?

---

So far I've tried three methods:

1. With a Ubertooth dogle and his Kismet plugin, I can see a lot of traffic, but I can't identify the correct device (the vendor is almost unknown). Also, I don't know why but Kismet doesn't let me do channel hopping, so I can only scan the channel 37 (most likely the device doesn't use this channel ?).
2. With a HackRF, but same problem, in all the noise I can't identify the device.
3. With a nRF52840 and a sniffing firmware, I can see a lot of traffic but can't identify the right dongle.